# adding event listeners to dynamically added html elements

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I have a problem adding event listeners to dynamically added html elements.

The scenario is that a number of 'forms' are stored in a database and displayed sequentially to a user. Each time a new form is displayed, event handlers are added to the new 'form' ie to the children elements. The id's of the html elements are the same for each 'form'.

Everything works fine for the first form, but when the second form is added, even tho the event handlers are added, they do not fire.

I have tried innumerable permutations of using .click, .on .off, .addEventListener .removeEventListener etc. but cannot seem to get this to work.

The code I am using is:

```
            //replace innerHTML             
            $( "#mob_html" ).off();                         //remove previous event listeners
            $( "#mob_html" ).remove();                          //remove html element
            $(form.html_str).insertAfter( "#event_hdr_div" );   // add new html element with form html stored in database

            // add event handler
            $('#'+child_id_1).click(function () {
                if (perm_fg==true) {
                    open();
                }
            });
            $('#'+child_id_1).click(function () {
                if (perm_fg==true) {
                    open();
                }
            });
```

Any suggestions much appreciated!

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle to check the exact problem?

Comment: I don't fully understand the scenario, but why don't you add a class and simply bind the listening of events once st the beginning with on(). The advantage of on() is that it binds even dynamically added elements that were created after its call.

Answer (score 0):

Select with document object

```
$(document).on('click', '.some-class', function() {
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of on() function you can bind your dynamically added element , but make sure to use latest version of jquery because it may not supported in earlier version of jquery.